# 2003 BMW M3 E46 Stalls in 1st Gear

Tags: manual-transmission, bmw, stall

I just bought a 2003 e46 Bmw M3 coupe with a manual transmission. i drove it from Chicago to Tennessee and it did fine until i got into tennessee. Now it wants to stall out in 1st gear. It starts right back up and I just dont get it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Stupid question on my part, but are you sure this isn't just driver error?

Comment: Could you describe what's happening? Does this happen with any gas applied? Do you mean it's stalling when you're rolling in 1st with the clutch engaged and no gas applied (RPM drops to idle speed but then stalls)?